# Проблема в AndroidManifest

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Не могу понять в чем проблема.
Где подчеркнуто красным пишет:'class' or 'interface'

[image: Где подчеркнуто пишет:'class' or 'interface' expected.]

Comment: а их имена точно с точки начинаются?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам должно помочь прописывание полного имени класса вместе с его пакетом

Comment: Нет, так не подходит.
Пишет ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: @Romag, а эти классы точно активити?

Comment: @Romag, может это ошибка студии. Попробуйте проект с нуля собрать. т.е. копирнуть проект в другую папку и открыт в студии через импорт проекта